# Get FB Id From URL

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I am writing an Android app that has the ability to like things on Facebook. In order to do this, I need to first obtain the Id of the object on Facebook. I thought I understood that I could just make a request to:

```
http://graph.facebook.com/?ids=[url]
```

and it would return some JSON with the id as well as the number of shares or whatever else. Apparently, this is not the case as the JSON that I get back contains the non-useful:

```
"id":"[url]"
```

There initially was some issue of the particular url I was using not being set up correctly in Facebook, but then we got that sorted out and in any case the above ids=[url] method does not work with ANY url that I have tried. If I do the same request but pass in the page's Facebook object id instead of the url, then I get the full object with all of the information from Facebook with the id correctly listed so I know that the page I am using in testing exists as a graph object.

So if the ids=[url] method does not work as a way to retrieve the object's id, then what is the correct way to do so programmatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I didn't solve the get-id-from-url problem, but I did find a way to just like a graph object directly using the following:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me/og.likes?method=POST
   &access_token=MY_ACCESS_TOKEN
   &object=MY_URL
```

Posting to this address, providing the url of the page to be liked and the access token of the user, will like that page on Facebook if a graph object exists for it.